# add increase change value between control and treatment in ggplot from a second dataframe R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this example dataframe with samestructure of my real one.
I calculate the increase change in a second dataframe and then I need to add this value to this boxplots:

```
test <- data.frame(city=c(rep("city1", 6), rep("city2", 6)), Treatment=c(rep("control", 3), rep("treat", 3)), replicate=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), y=c(12,24,13,15,26,16,13,23,45,34,12,24) )
test1 <- test %>%pivot_wider(names_from = "Treatment", values_from = "y") %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  summarise(treat=mean(treat), control=mean(control)) %>%
  mutate(perc_increase= (treat-control)/control)


means_meth <- "wilcoxon.test"
do_multicomp<- "no" 

test_t<- test%>%
  ggplot(aes(Treatment, y, fill=Treatment))+
  geom_boxplot(alpha=0.7) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 10),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1))) + xlab("") + 
  stat_compare_means(size=2)  +
  geom_text(data=test1, aes(perc_increase)) +
  facet_wrap(~city, scales = "free")                   
test_t
```

but I get this error:

```
Error in `geom_text()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'y' not found
```

How can I add this values in the boxplots?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, the OP wants to overlay a text geom with the perc_increase information from the `test1` data.frame into the original plot created with `test`.
It may be possible to create complex plots from multiple `data` objects for different geoms, but I usually see it as much easier if we combine all the data into a single data.frame, specially if we are using faceting or grids.
Here, we first `left_join` test and test1.
I had to include an additional step to create a variable to map the `y` in `geom_text`.
Then, with minor adjustments to the `aes` in `geom_text`, we get what looks like the desired output.

Please see that `percent_increase` does not seem to match the shift in the medians from the boxplots, because it is based on the difference of means.

A minor tip: always include the required libraries so we can reproduce the issues better. In this case, the use of `ggpubr` was not obvious, but `stat_compare_means` depends on this package.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

test2 <- left_join(test, test1) |> 
    mutate(y_text = max(y), .by = city)
    
test_t<- test2%>%
    ggplot(aes(Treatment, y, fill=Treatment))+
    geom_boxplot(alpha=0.7) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") + 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 10),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1))) + xlab("") + 
    stat_compare_means(size=2)  +
    geom_text(vjust = 2,
              aes(x = 1.5,
                  y = y_text,
                  label = str_glue("perc_increase:{scales::percent(perc_increase)}")
                  )
              ) +
    facet_wrap(~city, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works! However, would it be possible to keep the scale y free?

Comment: Glad it works. Please consider upvoting or accepting if an answer helps. What do you mean by "keep the scale y free"?

Comment: Oh, I see now. Somehow the aes `y = max(y)` is overriding the `scales =  "free"` below. Will look into that

Comment: Got it. See the updated answer